# What is the best way to create a pentadiagonal sparse matrix for finite difference method in c/c++?

Tags: c++, c, sparse-matrix

In MATLAB, it is very convenient to create a pentadiagonal sparse matrix using commands like this:

```
I = eye(m);  % create identity matrix
e = ones(m,1); % create an array of all 1's
T = spdiags([e -4*e e],[-1 0 1],m,m); 
S = spdiags([e e],[-1 1],m,m);
A = (kron(I,T) + kron(S,I))/hˆ2;
```

I was wondering if there is any neat trick to do the same in c/c++.

Comment: Are you using any particular matrix library?

Comment: Just Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms (BLAS)

Answer (score 2):

There is no sparse Matrix type in C++. But there are a lot of open source algebra libraries around the web (or you can write your own).

Boost [uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) supports sparse matrices, and it's probably the best choice if you want just to "experiment" finite differences. 
If you need more advanced solvers, you should take a look at [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/), or consider the C version of [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/).

As for your original question, as far as i know none of those libraries implements a `kron` function, since it is only a "convenience" routine.

Comment: uBLAS would probably be closest in terms of what the library was created to address.

Comment: Worth noting that uBLAS supports banded matrices as sparse, which are likely to be slightly more efficient. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/banded.htm